# Issues publishing WPF ClickOnce project using MSBuild

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild

I have a WPF project in Visual Studio 2017 that correctly publishes if I go on the project properties and publish it from there it does so just the way I want, but when I run `msbuild /target:publish` it creates an unwanted .exe file.

Furthermore, there's another option I enabled on Visual Studio which is in the Deployment tab called "deployment web page", which I just put "clickonce.htm".

So, when I publish using Visual Studio I get these files:

- Application Files
- clickonce.htm
- [ProjectName].application
- setup.exe

And when I use MSBuild:

- Application Files
- [ProjectName].application
- [ProjectName].exe
- setup.exe

How can I make it so that MSBuild outputs the same as Visual Studio?